# How to convert string to class sub-attribute with Python

Tags: python, class, attributes

I know I can get a Class's attributes with a string like this:

```
object.attribute = 'foo'
x = 'attribute'
getattr(object, x)
>>> 'foo'
```

Is there a way to "go deeper" into the object's attributes with a string?  In other words, if my object contains another object, how can I get the the sub-object's attributes with a string?  For example:

```
object.object.attribute
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `operator.attrgetter` function does this:

```
class Foo: pass
f = Foo()
f.bar = Foo()
f.bar.baz = Foo()
f.bar.baz.quux = "Found me!"

import operator
print operator.attrgetter("bar.baz.quux")(f)     # prints "Found me!"
```

Comment: HA! I forgot the `attrgetter` follows dot notation

Comment: Even better, but thanks anyway @jdi.. I learned more about lambdas from your answer.

Comment: @MFB: No worries. Ned's answer is better since its a stdlib version of the same thing that is also faster.

Answer (score 6):

I love the recipe given in this [link](http://mousebender.wordpress.com/2006/11/10/recursive-getattrsetattr/) (actually the comment is even better though)

Example borrowed from Claudiu's answer (which is great too):

```
class Foo: pass
f = Foo()
f.bar = Foo()
f.bar.baz = Foo()
f.bar.baz.quux = "Found me!"
```

A recursive getattr that follows dots:

```
>>> rgetattr = lambda o,a: reduce(getattr, a.split('.'), o)
>>> rgetattr(f, 'bar.baz.quux')
'Found me!'
```

The non-lambda version being:

```
def rgetattr(obj, attr):
    return reduce(getattr, attr.split('.'), obj)
```

Comment: Oh booyah.  Thanks to @Claudiu too

Comment: ah i haven't been doing enough functional programming lately. totally didn't see this as a `reduce`, but it obviously is

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> class Foo: pass

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar = Foo()
>>> f.bar.baz = Foo()
>>> f.bar.baz.quux = "Found me!"
>>> getattr(f, 'bar')
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x01EC5918>
>>> getattr(getattr(f, 'bar'), 'baz')
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x01EC5A30>
>>> getattr(getattr(getattr(f, 'bar'), 'baz'), 'quux')
'Found me!'
```

EDIT: Done as a simple method:

```
>>> def dynamic_lookup(obj, dot_attrs):
    attr_list = dot_attrs.split(".")
    while attr_list:
        obj = getattr(obj, attr_list.pop(0))
    return obj

>>> f
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x01EC50A8>
>>> dynamic_lookup(f, 'bar.baz.quux')
'Found me!'
```

Easily adaptable to take a list of strings (take `attr_list` directly instead of `dot_attrs`), but I thought the `.` notation as a string would look cooler...

Comment: Ah yes, but what about `object.object.object.attribute`? j/k :-)

Comment: That's cool.  How could I build the final method from a list of strings?